# Java streams zip two lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, concatenation

I have a HashSet of Persons. A person has a firstName, lastName and age like: Person("Hans", "Man", 36)

My task is to get a list of the persons who are older than 17, sort them by age and concat the firstName with the lastName 
like: ["Hans Man","another name", "another name"]

Im just allowed to import:

`import java.util.stream.Stream;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.ArrayList;`

My idea was to sort them first, map the names in separate Streams and to zip them, but it doesn't work.

```
public static void getNamesOfAdultsSortedByAge(Stream<Person> stream){

    Stream<Person> result = stream;
    Stream<Person> result1 = result.filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 18)
                            .sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.getAge(),y.getAge()));


    Stream<String> firstName = result1.map(Person::getFirstName);
    Stream<String> lastName = result1.map(Person::getLastName);

    Stream<String> result3 = concat(firstName, lastName);

    List<String> result4 = result3.collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result4);
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You’re thinking too complicated. Just use `map(p -> p.getFirstName()+" "+p.getLastName())`. This has nothing to do with zipping. And don’t store each stream stage into another variable. Just chain the steps, `List<String> result = stream.filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 18) .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge)) .map(p -> p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName()) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do so using :

```
public static void getNamesOfAdultsSortedByAge(Stream<Person> stream) {
    List<String> sorted = stream.filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 18)
                                .sorted((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.getAge(),y.getAge()))
                                .map(e -> e.getFirstName() + " " + e.getLastName())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
}
```

Here we just `map` the sorted stream by concatenating the first name and then the last name, after which we use the `.collect()` terminal operation to collect it to a list.

Comment: why did you edit it? the first one was the solution I was looking for because Im not allowed to import java.util.Comparator

Comment: Thought it was cleaner, missed out your constraints. Changed it back.

Comment: @oddi what does this even mean "you are not allowed to import `java.util.Comparator`"? I've never heard of such a strange import agreement... but you know that you can also use: `java.util.Comparator.comparingInt` and no import would be visible? ;-)

Comment: @Roland : I believe an up-vote is in-order for the confusion caused ;)

Comment: @NicholasK you may rather want to look up my answer instead ;-)

Comment: @NicholasK by the way... you know that you can also easily "rollback" a change? (just look at the revisions... there is its own "rollback"-link...) just in case you require that again at some time...

Comment: @Roland I´m a student and the tasks are always to complete codes with deleted methods without changing anything. Its really annoying but i have to deal with it.

Comment: well... then even more so I (clearly my personal opinion) would use the `Comparator`... whoever made that assignment/task probably didn't know it him/herself... why else would he/she used that construct otherwise? So: sharing is caring... I would at least report back the usage of `Comparator.comparingInt` ;-)

Comment: Suggestion: While you were editing, you could've kept both the solutions in your answers as alternates. Just that `Comparator.comparingInt` shouldn't really have been another answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> matching = Lists.newArrayList(
            new Person("Joey", "Tribiani", 28),
            new Person("Rachel", "Green", 12),
            new Person("Ross", "Geller", 114),
            new Person("Chandler", "Bing", 17)).stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 17)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))
            .map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName())
            .collect(toList());
}
```

If you need to change sorting order just reverse the comparator:

```
Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed()
```

Comment: Why do you think the comparator needs to be `reversed()`?

Comment: Because you've written "sort them by age" not mentioning the ordering. Wanted to show how to control items ordering.

Comment: didn't need it, but im glad to know reversed() now

Comment: @g-t I did not write anything about it, but the OP provided a code example which contains a comparator clearly using ascending order.

Comment: Fine. Removed reversed() but left a note for someone who might need descending order.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
Stream<String> firstName = result1.map(Person::getFirstName);
Stream<String> lastName = result1.map(Person::getLastName);
```

After the first `map`, the `Stream` is of type `String` which doesn't fit `Person::getLastName`. You need to concat within the first `map()` call itself.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand the Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside `getNamesOfAdultsSortedByAge` method:

```
stream
    .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 17)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
    .map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I suppose it should suit your needs. `filter` filters people that are only 18 or older, second line sorts given by `getAge` predicate, third just maps `Person` instance to a string containing `%firstName% %lastName%`, and fourth collects the result into a list.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following and as you have strange rules regarding the imports, I hide that one for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) deliberately:

```
List<String> result = stream.filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 18)
                            .sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
                            .map(p -> p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I know of some rules that imply that no other dependency should be used than the one listed on the "allowed list of dependencies", but I've never heard of a rule that only allows to use like 4 imports but disallows one of the most important ones. If [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) would be an internal interface/class I could understand it, but it's an essential interface. You even use it as a functional interface if you write `(x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.getAge(),y.getAge())`, so I really don't get why this import shouldn't be allowed. That being said: my solution does not require you to use an import to [`java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Have fun using it. It really makes comparisons easier and less error-prone (just imagine two similarly named methods and you catched the wrong one by mistake... have fun finding that error ;-)).

Comment: I am exactly your opinion, tanks for your detailed comment, I didn't know that you can use it that way.